# How to show DIV just on top of button

Tags: asp.net, html, styles, position

I have a custom control, which has a Button + image, if image(down arrow) is clicked, a DIV should display, just like Dropdownlist.

However, its pushing the page contents to down to display the DIV. How to fix this.

1. It should just behave like  dropdown
2. List should display on top of Button instead button

   ```
   <table id="container" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
   <tr>
       <td>
           <asp:Button ID="btnPost" runat="server" CssClass="postButton" OnClick="btnPost_Click" />
           <asp:Button ID="btnDropDown" runat="server" CssClass="dropdownButton" OnClick="btnDropDown_Click" />
       </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>
           <div runat="server" id="divDropDownPanel" visible="false" style="text-align: left;
               overflow: scroll; float: left; border: thin solid lightgrey; width: 160px; height: 120px;
               background-color: #FFFFFF; position: absolute; z-index: 999;">
               <asp:Repeater ID="rptDropDownContent" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptDropDownContent_ItemDataBound">
                   <HeaderTemplate>
                       <table>
                   </HeaderTemplate>
                   <ItemTemplate>
                       <tr>
                           <td align="left">
                               <asp:CheckBox ID="chkChannel" runat="server" />
                           </td>
                       </tr>
                   </ItemTemplate>
                   <FooterTemplate>
                       </tr> </table>
                   </FooterTemplate>
               </asp:Repeater>
               <br />
           </div>
       </td>
   </tr>
   ```

Comment: have you code anything  ?

Comment: Post your code, or even better, post a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: [link](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwcgqD6WpPnvQlNiS2NadUZYa0E/edit?usp=sharing)

Please see the output of above code.